# django form not saving updated value

Tags: django, django-forms

I have the following form save process in my view:

```
if request.method == "POST":
        form = PersonDetailForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=customer)
        if form.is_valid():
            print(form.cleaned_data['first_name']) //prints corrected updated value
            saved_customer = form.save()
            print(saved_customer.first_name) //prints the old wrong value
```

My model looks like this:

```
class Customer(models.Model): 
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)  
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
```

Here is my form class:

```
class PersonDetailForm(forms.ModelForm):


    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = (
                  'first_name',
                  'last_name'
                  )
```

The problem is that the form is not saving the updated first name.

When I print the cleaned_data is prints the correct updated value, but when I print the result of the saved form (saved_customer) it prints the old first name.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does your model look like?

Comment: did you try to print the `request.POST` to see whether it has the post values...

Comment: please write your form class in question

Comment: @KuskoAndrew I added it

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the problem is, but you could try:

```
if form.is_valid():
    f_customer = form.save(commit=False)
    f_customer.first_name = form.cleaned_data.get('first_name')
    f_customer.save()
```

If that still doesn't work, then I would think something is wrong with your Customer.save() or maybe you have a pre_save receiver set up doing something unexpected.